# License key of Android replaced with trial key

Tags: xamarin

I'm using Xamarin studio for my projects. During one of them I've installed (Xamarin Profiler Preview) plugin in order to locate memory drain. I used a trial version of this plugin in order to check if it can be useful for my purposes or not.
Unfortunately even after uninstalling this plugin my license key of whole Xamarin studio for android replaced with trial key.

Could be great if you could help me with that.

Answer (score 2):

For licensing issues please email support@xamarin.com directly so we can assist.